# code won't run after compilation on kali

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compilation

We are compiling an application that is required to communicate with FPGA. 
The protocol is normally handled by the COM port.  I use kali linux to compile the source code but the output won't launch.  When i use `sudo ./new`  I get

```
open() failed :no such a file or directory
```

I used  `gcc -o new code.c` to compile it, and then:

```
g++ -o new code.c
chmod +x
```

---

The code is 100 % working:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SERIAL "/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_TTL232R-3V3_FT90HST3-if00-port0"

static int fd;    
static char *name;

#define N 1024

static struct {
    uint8_t is_xx;
    uint8_t val;
    unsigned int addr;
    unsigned int data;
    unsigned int p3;
} inst[N];

static uint8_t map[16][256];

static void
dump_instructions(int num)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
        if (inst[i].is_xx) {
            printf(" XX");
        } else {
            printf(" %02X", inst[i].val);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
        printf(" %02X", inst[i].p3);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


static int
read_line(char *buf, size_t len)
{
    fd_set fds;
    struct timeval tv;
    ssize_t n;

    while (len > 0) {

        if (read(fd, buf, 1) != 1) {
            FD_ZERO(&fds);
            FD_SET(fd, &fds);

            tv.tv_sec = 1;
            tv.tv_usec = 0;

            if (select(fd+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv) != 1) {
                return -1;
            }

            if (!FD_ISSET(fd, &fds)) {
                return -1;
            }

            n = read(fd, buf, 1);
            if (n == 0) {
                return -1;
            } else if (n < 0) {
                if (errno == EINTR) {
                    continue;
                }
                return -1;
            }
        }

        if (*buf == '\n') {
            continue;
        }

        if (*buf == '\r') {
            *buf = '\0';
            return 0;
        }

        buf++;
        len--;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "[-] read_line() ran out of buffer\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static void
write_or_die(char *buf, size_t len)
{
    ssize_t n;

    while (len) {
        //write(1, buf, len);
        n = write(fd, buf, len);
        if (n <= 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR) continue;
            perror("[-] write() failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        buf += n;
        len -= n;
    }
}


static void
serial_sync(void)
{
    char buf[512];

    while (read_line(buf, sizeof(buf)) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[*] sync [%s]\n", buf);
    }
}

static void
init_serial(void)
{
    int opt;
#if 1
    struct termios tty;

    if ((fd = open(SERIAL, O_RDWR)) == -1) {
        perror("[-] open() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    tcgetattr(fd, &tty);
    cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t)B500000);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)B500000);

    /* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070632/#8082169 */
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
    tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
    tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
    tty.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty);
#else
    int flag = 1;
    ex_net_tcp_connect(&fd, "127.0.0.1", 1337);
    setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *)&flag, sizeof(flag));
#endif

    opt = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
    if (opt < 0) {
        perror("[-] fcntl(F_GETFL)");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    opt |= O_NONBLOCK;
    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, opt) < 0) {
        perror("[-] fcntl(F_SETFL)");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    serial_sync();
}

static void
run_task(size_t num)
{
    char tag[4];
    char buf[4096*16];
    size_t i;
    int retries = 0;

    do {
        tag[0] = 'A' + (rand() % 26);
        tag[1] = 'A' + (rand() % 26);
        tag[2] = 'A' + (rand() % 26);
        tag[3] = 'A' + (rand() % 26);

        write_or_die(tag, 4);

        for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
            if (inst[i].is_xx) {
                write_or_die(" XX", 3);
            } else {
                snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), " %02X", inst[i].val);
                write_or_die(buf, 3);
            }
        }

        write_or_die("\r", 1);

        if (read_line(buf, sizeof(buf))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "[-] read_line() failed\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (memcmp(buf, tag, 4)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "[-] wrong tag\n");
            continue;
        }

        for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
            if (sscanf(buf+4+i*11, " %04X:%02X:%02X",
                &inst[i].addr,
                &inst[i].data,
                &inst[i].p3
            ) != 3) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (i == num) break;

    } while (serial_sync(), retries++ < 3);
}    

static int
find_next_instruction(int off, int max)
{
    int i, j;
    uint16_t next_addr = 0xF00D;

    fprintf(stderr, "[*] Finding next instruction...");

    for (i=0; i<max; i++) {  /* number of XX bytes */
        inst[off+i].is_xx = 0;
        inst[off+i+1].is_xx = 1;

        for (j=0; j<256; j++) {  /* instruction */
            inst[off+i].val = j;

            run_task(off+i+2);

            if (j == 0) {
                next_addr = inst[off+i+1].addr;
            } else {
                if (inst[off+i+1].addr != next_addr) {
                    fprintf(stderr, " done\n");
                    return off+i;
                }
            }
        }

        inst[off+i].is_xx = 1;
        fprintf(stderr, ".");
    }

    fprintf(stderr, " error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}    

static int
find_next_instruction_for_sure(int off, int map_num)
{
    int i;

    fprintf(stderr, "[*] Finding next instruction (for sure)...");

    for (i=0; i<32; i++) {
        inst[off+i+0].val = map[map_num+0][0x75];
        inst[off+i+0].is_xx = 0;
        inst[off+i+1].val = map[map_num+1][0xB0];
        inst[off+i+1].is_xx = 0;
        inst[off+i+2].is_xx = 0;
        inst[off+i+3].is_xx = 1;
        inst[off+i+4].is_xx = 1;
        inst[off+i+5].is_xx = 1;
        inst[off+i+6].is_xx = 1;

        inst[off+i+2].val = map[map_num+2][0x55];
        run_task(off+i+7);
        if (inst[off+i+6].p3 != 0x55) goto next;

        inst[off+i+2].val = map[map_num+2][0xAA];
        run_task(off+i+7);
        if (inst[off+i+6].p3 != 0xAA) goto next;

        fprintf(stderr, " done (skipping %d cycle%s)\n", i, i==1 ? "" : "s");
        //dump_instructions(off+i+7);

        inst[off+i+0].is_xx = 1;
        inst[off+i+1].is_xx = 1;
        inst[off+i+2].is_xx = 1;

        return off+i;
next:
        inst[off+i].is_xx = 1;
        fprintf(stderr, ".");
    }

    fprintf(stderr, " error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static void
find_p3_argument(int off)
{
    int i, j;

    fprintf(stderr, "[*] Finding P3 as an argument...");

    inst[off+0].is_xx = 0;
    inst[off+1].is_xx = 0;
    inst[off+2].is_xx = 1;
    inst[off+3].is_xx = 1;
    inst[off+4].is_xx = 1;
    inst[off+5].is_xx = 1;

#if 1
    /* XXX */
    inst[off+0].val = 0x7C;
    inst[off+1].val = 0xEE;
    fprintf(stderr, " hack\n");
    return;
    /* XXX */
#endif

    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
        inst[off+0].val = i;

        for (j=0; j<256; j++) {
            inst[off+1].val = j;

            run_task(off+6);

            if (inst[off+5].p3 != 0xFF) printf("[%02X:%02X;p3=%02X]", i, j, inst[off+5].p3);

            if (inst[off+5].p3 == 0x00) {
                fprintf(stderr, " done\n");
                fprintf(stderr, "[+] %02X %02X gives us 00\n", inst[off+0].val, inst[off+1].val);
                return;
            }
        }

        fprintf(stderr, ".");
    }

    fprintf(stderr, " error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}    

static void
find_move_or_and_to_p3(int off)
{
    int i, j, k;
    uint8_t res;
    int m;
    uint8_t movmap[3][256];
    int err;

    fprintf(stderr, "[*] Finding MOV and ANL instructions to P3...");

    inst[off+0].is_xx = 0;
    inst[off+1].is_xx = 0;
    inst[off+2].is_xx = 0;
    inst[off+3].is_xx = 1;
    inst[off+4].is_xx = 1;
    inst[off+5].is_xx = 1;

#if 0
    /* XXX */
    inst[off+0].val = 0xF1;
    inst[off+1].val = 0x5C;
    fprintf(stderr, " hack\n");
    return;
    /* XXX */
#endif

    m = 0;

    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {

        inst[off+0].val = i;
        inst[off+2].val = 0x55;
        run_task(off+6);

        res = inst[off+5].p3;

        inst[off+2].val = 0xAA;
        run_task(off+6);

        if (inst[off+5].p3 == res) goto nope;

        /* uh, this might be MOV, ANL, or XOR */
        fprintf(stderr, "!");

        for (j=0; j<256; j++) {
            inst[off+2].val = j;
            run_task(off+6);
            movmap[m][j] = inst[off+5].p3;

            for (k=0; k<j; k++) {
                if (movmap[m][j] == movmap[m][k]) goto nope;
            }
        }

        /* yep, all good */
        fprintf(stderr, "!");
        m++;
        if (m > 1) {
            err = 0;
            for (j=0; !err && j<256; j++) {
                if (movmap[0][j] != movmap[m-1][j]) err = 1;
            }
            if (!err) goto done;
        }
        if (m > 2) {
            err = 0;
            for (j=0; !err && j<256; j++) {
                if (movmap[1][j] != movmap[m-1][j]) err = 1;
            }
            if (!err) goto done;
            fprintf(stderr, " error\n");
            fprintf(stderr, "[-] Found three instructions, but no match!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

nope:
        fprintf(stderr, ".");
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "[-] Unable to find a MOV or ANL instruction.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

done:
    fprintf(stderr, " done\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "[+] %02X %02X XX is perfect\n", inst[off+0].val, inst[off+1].val);
}    

static void
find_nop_and_move_or_and(int off, uint8_t *map)
{
    int i, ii, j, k;
    int r = rand();
    int rr = rand();
    uint8_t res;
    int m;
    uint8_t movmap[3][256];
    int err;

    fprintf(stderr, "[*] Finding NOP-like instruction, followed by MOV and ANL instructions...");

    inst[off+0].is_xx = 0;
    inst[off+1].is_xx = 1;
    inst[off+2].is_xx = 0;
    inst[off+3].is_xx = 0;
    inst[off+4].is_xx = 0;
    inst[off+5].is_xx = 1;
    inst[off+6].is_xx = 1;
    inst[off+7].is_xx = 1;

    m = 0;

    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
    for (ii=0; ii<256; ii++) {

        inst[off+0].val = (i + r) & 0xFF;
        inst[off+2].val = (ii + rr) & 0xFF;
        inst[off+3].val = map[0xB0];
        inst[off+4].val = 0x55;
        run_task(off+8);

        res = inst[off+7].p3;

        inst[off+4].val = 0xAA;
        run_task(off+8);

        if (inst[off+7].p3 == res) goto nope;

        /* uh, this might be MOV, ANL, or XOR */
        fprintf(stderr, ".!");

        for (j=0; j<256; j++) {
            inst[off+4].val = j;
            run_task(off+8);
            movmap[m][j] = inst[off+7].p3;

            for (k=0; k<j; k++) {
                if (movmap[m][j] == movmap[m][k]) goto nope;
            }
        }

        /* yep, all good */
        fprintf(stderr, "!");
        m++;
        if (m > 1) {
            err = 0;
            for (j=0; !err && j<256; j++) {
                if (movmap[0][j] != movmap[m-1][j]) err = 1;
            }
            if (!err) goto done;
        }
        if (m > 2) {
            err = 0;
            for (j=0; !err && j<256; j++) {
                if (movmap[1][j] != movmap[m-1][j]) err = 1;
            }
            if (!err) goto done;
            fprintf(stderr, " error\n");
            fprintf(stderr, "[-] Found three instructions, but no match!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
nope:
        do { } while (0);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, ".");
    }

    fprintf(stderr, " end\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "[-] Unable to find a NOP, followed by a MOV or ANL instruction.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

done:
    fprintf(stderr, " done\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "[+] %02X XX %02X XX XX is perfect\n", inst[off+0].val, inst[off+2].val);
}    

static void
make_p_c_map(int mapnum, int off)
{
    int i, j;

    fprintf(stderr, "[*] Mapping P to C #%d...", mapnum);

    inst[off+0].is_xx = 0;
    inst[off+1].is_xx = 0;
    inst[off+2].is_xx = 0;
    inst[off+3].is_xx = 1;
    inst[off+4].is_xx = 1;
    inst[off+5].is_xx = 1;
    inst[off+6].is_xx = 1;
    inst[off+7].is_xx = 1;

    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
        inst[off+2].val = i;
        run_task(off+8);
        //fprintf(stderr, "[C:%02X -> P:%02X]\n", i, inst[off+5].p3);
        map[mapnum][inst[off+5].p3] = i;
        if ((i & 0xF) == 0xF) fprintf(stderr, ".");
    }

    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<i; j++) {
            if (map[mapnum][i] == map[mapnum][j]) {
                fprintf(stderr, " error\n");
                for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "[C:%02X -> P:%02X]\n", map[mapnum][i], i);
                }
                dump_instructions(off+8);
                inst[off+2].val = 0x41;
                run_task(off+8);
                dump_instructions(off+8);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

    fprintf(stderr, " done\n");
}


static void
check_clip_connection(void)
{
    int i, j;
    int err = 0;
    char addr_is_lo[15] = {0};
    char addr_is_hi[15] = {0};
    char data_is_lo[8] = {0};
    char data_is_hi[8] = {0};
    struct {
        uint16_t addr;
        uint8_t data;
    } x[16];

    fprintf(stderr, "[*] Checking clip connection...");

    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
        inst[i].is_xx = 1;
    }

    run_task(16);
    for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
        x[i].addr = inst[i].addr;
        x[i].data = inst[i].data;
    }

    run_task(16);
    for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
        if (x[i].addr != inst[i].addr) fprintf(stderr, "A");
        if (x[i].data != inst[i].data) fprintf(stderr, "D (%02X vs %02X)", x[i].data, inst[i].data);
        fprintf(stderr, ".");
    }

    run_task(16);
    for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
        if (x[i].addr != inst[i].addr) fprintf(stderr, "A");
        if (x[i].data != inst[i].data) fprintf(stderr, "D (%02X vs %02X)", x[i].data, inst[i].data);
        fprintf(stderr, ".");
    }

    run_task(N);
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
        //fprintf(stderr, "%4d addr=%04X, data=%02X\n", i, inst[i].addr, inst[i].data);
        for (j=0; j<15; j++) {
            if (1 & (inst[i].addr >> j)) {
                addr_is_hi[j] = 1;
            } else {
                addr_is_lo[j] = 1;
            }
        }
        for (j=0; j<8; j++) {
            if (1 & (inst[i].data >> j)) {
                data_is_hi[j] = 1;
            } else {
                data_is_lo[j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    fprintf(stderr, " addr [");
    for (j=14; j>=0; j--) {
        if (addr_is_hi[j] && addr_is_lo[j]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "X");
        } else if (addr_is_hi[j]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "1");
            err = 1;
        } else if (addr_is_lo[j]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "0");
            err = 1;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "?");
            err = 1;
        }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "]; data [");
    for (j=7; j>=0; j--) {
        if (data_is_hi[j] && data_is_lo[j]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "X");
        } else if (data_is_hi[j]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "1");
            err = 1;
        } else if (data_is_lo[j]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "0");
            err = 1;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "?");
            err = 1;
        }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "]\n");

    //if (err) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int off0, off1, off3;
    int i, j;
    char path[32];
    int resfd;
    int mo;
    int data_begin;

    if (argc < 2) {
        name = "unknown";
    } else {
        name = argv[1];
    }

    srand(getpid());
    setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    init_serial();

    check_clip_connection();

    off0 = find_next_instruction(0, 100);
    fprintf(stderr, "[+] First instruction found at offset %d\n", off0);

    find_p3_argument(off0);

    find_move_or_and_to_p3(off0);
    make_p_c_map(0, off0);

    find_nop_and_move_or_and(off0, map[0]);
    make_p_c_map(1, off0+2);

    find_nop_and_move_or_and(off0+2, map[1]);
    make_p_c_map(2, off0+4);

    for (i=0; i<16-3; i++) {
        off1 = off0 + 4;
        for (j=0; j<i+1; j++) {
            inst[off1+0].is_xx = 0;
            inst[off1+0].val = map[j][0x00];
            inst[off1+1].is_xx = 1;
            off1 += 2;
        }
        inst[off1+0].val = map[i+1][0x75];
        inst[off1+1].val = map[i+2][0xB0];
        make_p_c_map(i+3, off1);
    }

    off3 = off0 + 4;
    mo = 0;

    /* MOV A, MCON */
    inst[off3+0].val = map[mo++][0xE5];
    inst[off3+0].is_xx = 0;
    inst[off3+1].val = map[mo++][0xC6];
    inst[off3+1].is_xx = 0;

    off3 = find_next_instruction_for_sure(off3+2, mo);

    /* MOV P3, A */
    inst[off3+0].val = map[mo++][0xF5];
    inst[off3+0].is_xx = 0;
    inst[off3+1].val = map[mo++][0xB0];
    inst[off3+1].is_xx = 0;

    off3 = find_next_instruction_for_sure(off3+2, mo);

    inst[off3+0].is_xx = 1;
    inst[off3+1].is_xx = 1;
    inst[off3+2].is_xx = 1;

    run_task(off3+3);

    fprintf(stderr, "[*] MCON = 0x%02X\n", inst[off3+2].p3);

    data_begin = 0xF & (inst[off3+2].p3 >> 4);
    fprintf(stderr, "[*] code = 0x0000 to 0x%XFFF\n", data_begin-1);
    if (data_begin == 8) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[*] no data\n");
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "[*] data = 0x%X000 to 0x7FFF\n", data_begin);
    }

    for (j=0; j<16; j++) {

        snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s-%X-XXXXXX.bin", name, j);

        if ((resfd = mkstemps(path, 4)) < 0) {
            perror("[-] mkstemps() failed");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        off3 = off0 + 4;
        mo = 0;

        /* MOV DPTR, 0x0000 */
        inst[off3+0].val = map[mo++][0x90];
        inst[off3+0].is_xx = 0;
        inst[off3+1].val = map[mo++][0x00];
        inst[off3+1].is_xx = 0;
        inst[off3+2].val = map[mo++][0x00];
        inst[off3+2].is_xx = 0;

        off3 = find_next_instruction_for_sure(off3+3, mo);

        /* MOV A, 0x00 */
        inst[off3+0].val = map[mo++][0x74];
        inst[off3+0].is_xx = 0;
        inst[off3+1].val = map[mo++][0x00];
        inst[off3+1].is_xx = 0;

        off3 = find_next_instruction_for_sure(off3+2, mo);

        /* MOVC A, @(A+DPTR) */
        inst[off3+0].val = map[mo++][0x93];
        inst[off3+0].is_xx = 0;

        off3 = find_next_instruction_for_sure(off3+1, mo);

        /* MOV P3, A */
        inst[off3+0].val = map[mo++][0xF5];
        inst[off3+0].is_xx = 0;
        inst[off3+1].val = map[mo++][0xB0];
        inst[off3+1].is_xx = 0;

        off3 = find_next_instruction_for_sure(off3+2, mo);

        inst[off3+0].is_xx = 1;
        inst[off3+1].is_xx = 1;
        inst[off3+2].is_xx = 1;

        fprintf(stderr, "[*] Dumping code...");

        for (i=0x0000; i<0x1000*data_begin; i++) {
            inst[off0+5].val = map[1][0xFF & (i >> 8)];
            inst[off0+6].val = map[2][0xFF & (i >> 0)];
            run_task(off3+3);
            if (write(resfd, &inst[off3+2].p3, 1) != 1) {
                perror("[-] write() failed");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            if ((i & 0x3FF) == 0x3FF) fprintf(stderr, ".");
        }

        fprintf(stderr, " done\n");

        off3 = off0 + 4;
        mo = 0;

        /* MOV DPTR, 0x7FFF */
        inst[off3+0].val = map[mo++][0x90];
        inst[off3+0].is_xx = 0;
        inst[off3+1].val = map[mo++][0x7F];
        inst[off3+1].is_xx = 0;
        inst[off3+2].val = map[mo++][0xFF];
        inst[off3+2].is_xx = 0;

        off3 = find_next_instruction_for_sure(off3+3, mo);

        /* MOVX A, @DPTR */
        inst[off3+0].val = map[mo++][0xE0];
        inst[off3+0].is_xx = 0;

        off3 = find_next_instruction_for_sure(off3+1, mo);

        /* MOV P3, A */
        inst[off3+0].val = map[mo++][0xF5];
        inst[off3+0].is_xx = 0;
        inst[off3+1].val = map[mo++][0xB0];
        inst[off3+1].is_xx = 0;

        off3 = find_next_instruction_for_sure(off3+2, mo);

        inst[off3+0].is_xx = 1;
        inst[off3+1].is_xx = 1;
        inst[off3+2].is_xx = 1;

        fprintf(stderr, "[*] Dumping data...");

        for (i=0x1000*data_begin; i<0x8000; i++) {
            inst[off0+5].val = map[1][0xFF & (i >> 8)];
            inst[off0+6].val = map[2][0xFF & (i >> 0)];
            run_task(off3+3);
            if (write(resfd, &inst[off3+2].p3, 1) != 1) {
                perror("[-] write() failed");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            if ((i & 0x3FF) == 0x3FF) fprintf(stderr, ".");
        }

        fprintf(stderr, " done\n");

        close(resfd);

    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: How do you know the code is working, if you can't run the compiled code?  Or do you just mean that it compiles without errors?

Comment: the author of the code show screenshot .its working
i don't know if its c or c++ code

Comment: https://ibb.co/bMmbAm

Comment: Better compile with `gcc -Wall -g -o new code.c` ; you'll then be able to use the `gdb` debugger

Comment: That path for `SERIAL` appears to point at a specific adapter instance. Are you able to find that path by looking in `/dev/`?

Comment: it seem the author used usb to rs232 converter
sorry i'm new to this ,

Comment: next time tell the author to ask the question himself, because if you don't understand the code, you won't understand the problem, nor the solution, everybody will be confused and the question will be closed. You're just lucky that you got an answer that solved your problem this time. The one who codes should ask because he understand his code the most if it's a team work, especially that you have no clue if it's C or C++ or chinese

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the code fails because your serial device does not have the same name as the device on the programmer's system:

```
#define SERIAL "/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_TTL232R-3V3_FT90HST3-if00-port0"

if ((fd = open(SERIAL, O_RDWR)) == -1) {
    perror("[-] open() failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

You should pass the device name as a command line argument, or implement some sort of discovery mechanism.

Comment: thanks , i did
'./new SERIAL COM0 ' but still the same error

Comment: The path is hardcoded, you'll have to change the source code.